# Add to array only if something isn't in it already?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to insert a class into a classes array for a student, but only if the class isn't there already. I read upsert takes care of this, but it adds the class to the array whether it's already there or not. Can someone lead me in the right direction?

```
Student.findOneAndUpdate(
    query,
    {$push: {"classes": {class_id: class_id, class_title: class_title, class_instructor: class_instructor}}},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    callback
);
```

Comment: `Student.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$addToSet: {classes: theIdToAdd}}, callback);`

Comment: Darn, it's still adding them

Comment: What do you mean by insert only if the class isn't there already? you are comparing class_id only or you want whole class object unique?

Comment: Roughly this Student = {email, classes=[ ]}

var chemistry = {_id: 4344343, title: "something, instructor: "someone"}

Then to only add chemistry to the student's classes if chemistry isn't there already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $ne

```
Student.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"classes.class_id":{$ne: class_id}}
    {$addToSet: {"classes": {class_id: class_id, class_title: class_title, class_instructor: class_instructor}}},
    {safe: true,},
    callback
)
```

;